# Regex: Check if there are more than x line breaks

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to validate a string according to the occurence of line breaks.
The input is okay if there are no more than say 6 line breaks.
The input it not okay if there are more than say 6 line breaks.
Of course between the line breaks can (but does not have to) occur other characters.
I need to solve this solely within the regular expression because I cannot add any additional code.

I tought about something like this:

```
/^(\r\n|\r|\n){0,6}$/ // not working :[
```

Comment: Try `return Regex.Matches(input, @"\r\n?|\n").Count <= 6;`

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is I just have control of the regex string. I cannot modify any code. Sorry, I should have mentioned. [Edited post]

Comment: Use this regex to match input with no more than 6 line breaks: `\A(?:.*\r?\n){0,6}.*\z`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^.*(?:\n.*){0,6}\z")
```

Or, if your line endings can be single CR/LF, you should bear in mind that in a .NET regex, `.` - without the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option - matches any chars but LF, and matches CR chars, so you will need to use something like

```cs
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[^\r\n]*(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)[^\r\n]*){0,6}\z")
```

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line feed (`\n`) char as many as possible (= a line)
- `(?:\n.*){0,6}` - zero to six consecutive occurrences of an LF char and then any zero or more chars other than an LF char as many as possible
- `\z` - the very end of string.

The second pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\r\n]*` - zero or more chars other than LF and CR as many as possible
- `(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)[^\r\n]*){0,6}` - zero to six occurrences of

  - `(?:\r\n?|\n)` - either CRLF, or CR, or LF
  - `[^\r\n]*` - zero or more chars other than LF and CR as many as possible
- `\z` - the very end of string.